# Problems with JPA Hibernate Query with 'Interval'

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need the possibility to retrieve the orders for the past 6 months for my backend application.

```
 @Query("Select ord From orders ord WHERE ord.created_date  <= (current_date  - INTERVAL '6 months')")
    List<Order> findOrders();
```

```
unexpected token: INTERVAL near line 1, column 70 [Select ord From orders ord WHERE ord.created_date  <= (current_date  INTERVAL '6 months')
```

After some research , I've found out that JPA does not support the INTERVAL definition.
Is there a workaround for archiving this particularly function ?

Comment: Try `(current_date - cast('6 months' AS INTERVAL))`. It should work, but I'm not confident enough to post it as an answer.

Comment: tried your version . Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Well does it crash when parsing in JPA or in the database? An error message would be useful.

Comment: JPQL and HQL do not support intervals, you will have to use the solution as provided by Adam Gaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case use the JPA provided functionality , where native sql code is not required.

```
  List<Order> findALLByCreatedDateBefore(Date fromDate);
```

and on java side invoke it

```
public void findOrders() {
    date = setMonthToJavaUtilDate(new Date(), -6);
    yourRepository.findOrders(fromDate)
    //your logic...
}

private Date setMonthToJavaUtilDate(Date date, int month) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.setTime(date);
    now.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    return now.getTime();
}
```

Comment: i like your approach but i guess you need too add to your Calendar and not set the month , since it could get to an exception now.set month -> requires (0-11)
---> now.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);

Answer (score 6):

You can parametrize your repository method by the date calculated inside the java code. Assuming `created_date` is of type `Instant` it would be something like:

```
@Query("FROM orders ord WHERE ord.created_date  >= :fromDate")
List<Order> findOrders(Instant fromDate);
```

and invoke it

```
Instant fromDate = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofDays(182));
yourRepository.findOrders(fromDate)
```

Comment: yes i guess this should be the way to go instead of creating a native query

Comment: also like this approach this should also work like a charm.